# Run time error 1004 message-what is wrong with my code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim wkbReport As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Dim Path1 As String
Dim file As String
Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Path1 = "C:\Users\vipul\Desktop\photos to arrange"

Set wkbReport = ThisWorkbook

            If Not Dir$(Path & "\data sh*" & ".*", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
                    file = Dir$(Path & "\data sh*" & ".*")
            Else
                    file = Dir$(Path1 & "\Data sh*" & ".*")
            End If

Set WB = Workbooks.Open(file)
```

In my case, there is two possiblities of my file ("Data sheet for ABC.xlsx") will be either on desktop or in folder "C:\Users\vipul\Desktop\photos to arrange".
Here in this code when my file named as "Data sheet for ABC.xlsx" is on Desktop, the code is running fine.
But, when that file is in "C:\Users\vipul\Desktop\photos to arrange" folder, it gives me error at Set WB = workbooks.Open(file)
Please guide me

Comment: `Dir$` doesn't return the full path... use `Path` or `Path1` in addition to the result of `Dir$`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the path in the open file.

try like this

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim wkbReport As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Dim Path1 As String
Dim file As String
Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Path1 = "C:\Users\vipul\Desktop\photos to arrange"

Set wkbReport = ThisWorkbook

            If Not Dir$(Path & "\data sh*" & ".*", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
                    file = Dir$(Path & "\data sh*" & ".*")
                    Path = Path & "\"
            Else
                    file = Dir$(Path1 & "\Data sh*" & ".*")
                    Path = Path1 & "\"
            End If

Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Path & file)
```